# Calculate electric potential and electric field of uniformly charged wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

> Say you have a uniformly charged straight wire of length $2L$ going from $-L$ to $+L$ along the $z$ axis with its midpoint located at $z=0$. What is the electrostatic potential, in cylindrical coordinates, for points in the midplane of the wire ($x,y$ plane)? From this electric potential, calculate the electric field in the $x,y$ plane.

My intuition is telling me that, because of the symmetry, the only direction the electric can be directed is in the xy-plane. So we have $$dq=\lambda dz$$ Thus, since $$dV=\frac{kdq}{r}$$ We have $$V=2\int_0^L \frac{kdq}{r}$$ Also $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ The integral is then $$2k\int_0^L \frac{\lambda dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$ Evaluating this I get $$V = 2 k \lambda \ln ( \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} + z)$$ I know it's not in spherical coordinates, but can someone tell me if this is right so far? If so, the electric field is then given by the negative gradient, correct?

Comment: One way to do a quick sanity check on this: very far ($r>>L$) from the source, one should expect the potential and field to behave in a particular way; make sure your final answer does!

Comment: You might also want to rewrite the logarithm with the other boundary term from the integral to get something like $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(\frac{a}{b})$. This way, the argument of the log is dimensionless. It's bad practice to have functions of dimensional quantities, something chemists refuse to understand.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not correct. Integral of reciprocal of a square root is not a logarithm (you say so in the last line).

Comment: I deleted an inappropriate comment and some obsolete/chatty ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integration is correct (if you didn't forget to multiply the result by 2 for 2L), the solution is correct. And yes the electric field is the negative gradient of the potential

Comment: Actually I forgot to evaluate the integral at z=0, so it's missing a term. Besides that, it's good.